# How to use Java Mission Control to monitor a JVM in a remote server?

Tags: java, jvm, jmc

Is it possible to use **JMC to monitor a JVM in a remote server?** If so how do i do it? Is there any specific java Flags to be invoked before using that? I tried creating a new JVM connection specifying all the details it asks in the wizard. But when i test the connection it cannot connect to that server. Since there were some configurations to be done to activate local jvm searching option, my guess is that i'm missing something here.(assuming that the server firewall is not blocking this connection) Appreciate if anyone could help with this.

Comment: Maybe this blog post could help you http://www.first8.nl/blog/using-mission-controle-for-remote-profiling/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, for easier tunneling, you can have the RMI registry and server on the same port, as described here: http://hirt.se/blog/?p=289.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, but if I move the RMI port to +1 then it works.